# Error in the protocol HTTPS WFS-T

Tags: wfs-t, http

The problem is that the main site uses the HTTPS protocol, and the GeoServer does not accept requests over the protocol
https://test.geoportal.samgau.com/geoserver/AkmolaRegion/wfs,
gives an error message

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><ows:ExceptionReport xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="1.0.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/ows http://test.geoportal.samgau.com/geoserver/schemas/ows/1.0.0/owsExceptionReport.xsd">
<ows:Exception exceptionCode="InvalidParameterValue" locator="typeName">
    <ows:ExceptionText>Could not locate {https://test.geoportal.samgau.com}001_1132201_ads_lin in catalog.</ows:ExceptionText>
</ows:Exception></ows:ExceptionReport>....
```

If I change the protocol to HTTP, then everything is ok

GeoServer message:

2020-09-22 18:24:06,311 ERROR [geoserver.ows] -
org.geoserver.wfs.WFSException: Could not locate {https://test.geoportal.samgau.com}001_1132201_ads_lin in catalog.

I can't figure out which direction to look in.
There is very little information on the Internet about this.
What should I do and how should I organize the work?

Comment: Please don't use pictures of the error messages or XML you send. Please [edit] your question to include a working and not working xml file and end point

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution.
It was about the typeName parameter.
It should have been left blank in the OpenLayers code.

```
const featureRequest = new ol.format.WFS().writeGetFeature({
        srsName: 'EPSG:3857',
        featureNS: 'http://openstreetmap.org',
       // featurePrefix: region,
        featureTypes: [layerName.replace(region, '')],
        outputFormat: 'application/json',
    });
```

Maybe someone will be useful in the future.